# mootools fail to inject an element at bottom of another one on ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mootools, internet-explorer-9

If I try to inject an element at the bottom of another one

```
var div = new Element('div', { id: 'thediv' }).inject(anotherdiv, 'bottom');
```

I get

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'appendChild': object is null or undefined 
mootools-core-1.3.2-full-compat.js, line 3437 character 3
```

these are the lines which cause the error in mootools1.3.2

```
bottom: function(context, element){
    element.appendChild(context);
},
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the error you get if *anotherdiv* doesn't have an *appendChild* method, such as if the script is run before *anotherdiv* exists, or has not been assigned a value that is a DOM element.